# Flash ROM from USB drive with DOS?

Tags: boot, hardware, flash, ms-dos

My home server PC has a P4 processor.  Windows seems unable to control the processor speed, so the processor heats up and the PC fan is running at full speed all day.  The event log says there is a known issue with the firmware, and I should flash the motherboard ROM.

On the ASUS website I found a new ROM version and a flasher.  Unfortunately, the flasher is a DOS application.  The server has a DVD drive and USB.

I was wondering, is it possible to boot into MS-DOS from a USB stick?  How do you create such a USB stick?

Answer (score 3):

You can use FreeDos.

**[HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://www.google.com/search?q=hp+usb+disk+storage+format+tool)**
**[FreeDos](ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.0/fdbasecd.iso)**

I was able to use recently this tutorial:
[CREATING A BOOTABLE DOS USB STICK FOR BIOS](http://ideatank.nullcat.de/217-creating-a-bootable-dos-usb-stick-for-bios-updates)

> 1. extract the directory **“odin”** from the FreeDOS .iso image
>   2. install **HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool** and run it. 
>   3. Select your usb stick, **“fat”** as filesystem, check **“Create a DOS startup disk”** and select the **“odin”** directory under **“using DOS system files located at”**.
>   4. press **“Start”**, wait a little bit and your usb stick is finished

Comment: Followed the tutorial and booted from the usb stick.  It displays "FreeDOS" and then stops doing anything.  Any tips welcome!